# User access control on S3 hosted content

Tags: amazon-s3, access-control

How should I control access to content on S3? For example, for a social media application. I host my photos and videos on S3. A user might upload content meant for a few friends only. How can I control access?

I know I could use IAM, but these are AWS users right? Not application users. I'd prefer not to create 1 policy for each user in my application.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at [AWS Post Presigned](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-UsingHTTPPOST.html), this will help.

You can implement the same using [minio client](https://github.com/minio/mc) aka `mc`. Supports all S3 compatible solutions.

We also libraries available for [Go](https://github.com/minio/minio-go), [Java](https://github.com/minio/minio-java), [.Net](https://github.com/minio/minio-dotnet), [Python](https://github.com/minio/minio-py), [nodeJs](https://github.com/minio/minio-js) languages.

PS: I am a contributor to minio project.

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is for uploads, how do I restract access to GETs?